# Botkit reply with an image

Tags: node.js, slack-api, botkit

Hello I was trying to make botkit reply with an image on my callback function but am unsure as to how `convo.say()` or `bot.reply()` would handle sending out images. Does anyone have experience making the slackbot replying with images?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using slack, it should be possible with interactive messages.

Here's an example message object from slack's own documentation of interactive messages (found here: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons)

```
{
    "text": "New comic book alert!",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "title": "The Further Adventures of Slackbot",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Volume",
                    "value": "1",
                    "short": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "Issue",
                    "value": "3",
            "short": true
                }
            ],
            "author_name": "Stanford S. Strickland",
            "author_icon": "http://a.slack-edge.com/7f18https://a.slack-edge.com/a8304/img/api/homepage_custom_integrations-2x.png",
            "image_url": "http://i.imgur.com/OJkaVOI.jpg?1"
        },
        {
            "title": "Synopsis",
            "text": "After @episod pushed exciting changes to a devious new branch back in Issue 1, Slackbot notifies @don about an unexpected deploy..."
        },
        {
            "fallback": "Would you recommend it to customers?",
            "title": "Would you recommend it to customers?",
            "callback_id": "comic_1234_xyz",
            "color": "#3AA3E3",
            "attachment_type": "default",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "recommend",
                    "text": "Recommend",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "recommend"
                },
                {
                    "name": "no",
                    "text": "No",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "bad"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

You can also create your own custom message from here https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder